# Update con datos de otra tabla y condiciones

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

estoy con un problemita que me está costando resolver.
Tengo que updetear una tabla que tiene su estado del registro en null de la cual puedo tomar el estado de otra tabla histórica pero debe cumplir ciertas condiciones y eso es lo que me complica.

```
Tabla 1
ID    Nom   Est
----- ----  -- 
20    Uno   NULL
30    Dos   NULL
40    Tres  NULL
```

Tabla 2

```
ID    IDTabla1   Est  Ap 
---   ---        ---  --
1     20         5    1
2     20         4    0
3     20         2    1
4     30         5    1
5     30         9    0
6     40         5    0
```

El campo tabla1.Est toma el valor de tabla2.Est siempre y cuando en tabla 2 tome el máximo tabla2.ID cuyo
Ap = 1

es decir, luego del update la tabla 1 debe quedar asi

```
Tabla 1
ID    Nom   Est
----- ----  -- 
20    Uno   2
30    Dos   5
40    Tres  NULL
```

Estuve intentando varios metodos de update, pero hasta el momento sólo pienso que lo puedo lograr con un cursor.
Hay alguna manera sensilla de generar un update o deberé recurrir al cursor?

Gracias

Comment: utiliza update con inner join, pon tu codigo de lo que has realizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar una consulta de actualización:

```
update Tabla1
       set Est = M.Est
       from Tabla1 T
       inner join (select IDTabla1,
                          max(Est) Est
                          FROM Tabla2
                          where Ap = 1
                          group by IDTabla1
       ) M
       on T.ID = M.IDTabla1
```

La subconsulta nos retorna el máximo `Est` por cada `IDTabla1`, luego, simplemente combinamos esta consulta mediante un `inner join` con la tabla original que queremos actualizar.

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estaba cerca con lo que yo habia planteado.

Comment: añado para que el que le pueda llegar a servir la respuesta, el 'where' debe ir antes del 'group by' (en  group by IDTabla1
                          where Ap = 1)

Comment: @campito, Gracias por notarlo, se me escapó

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias opciones para obtener ese resultado. Lo más lógico es utilizar las funciones de ordenamiento que tenemos disponibles mediante CTEs.

```
--Esto es solo para crear los datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE Tabla1(
    ID int,
    Nom varchar(100),
    Est int
)
INSERT INTO Tabla1(ID, Nom)
VALUES(20, 'Uno'),(30, 'Dos'),(40, 'Tres')

CREATE TABLE Tabla2(
    ID int,
    IDTabla1 int,
    Est int,
    Ap bit
)
INSERT INTO Tabla2
VALUES( 1, 20, 5, 1),
      ( 2, 20, 4, 0),
      ( 3, 20, 2, 1),
      ( 4, 30, 5, 1),
      ( 5, 30, 9, 0),
      ( 6, 40, 5, 0);

--Aquí inicia la solución
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        --Asignamos un número ordenando desde el mayor ID hasta el menor
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY IDTabla1 ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
    FROM Tabla2
    WHERE Ap = 1 --Solo usamos filas con Ap = 1
)
UPDATE t SET
    Est = c.Est
FROM Tabla1 t
--Hacemos un join con la CTE para obtener los datos de la tabla
JOIN CTE c ON t.ID = c.IDTabla1
WHERE c.rn = 1; --Usamos solo el primer valor de cada IDTabla1
```

Hay otro medio que pareciera más lógico pero me parece un poco menos eficiente ya que actualiza las filas múltiples veces, pero lo dejo por cultura general.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        LAST_VALUE (Est) OVER( PARTITION BY IDTabla1 ORDER BY ID 
                                ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) LastEst
    FROM Tabla2
    WHERE Ap = 1
)
UPDATE t SET
    Est = c.LastEst
FROM Tabla1 t
JOIN CTE c ON t.ID = c.IDTabla1
```

Comment: Hola Luis, intenté correr la primera opcion pero me indica 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Le di mil vueltas pero si saco el 'as' me arroja 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'CTE'.

La db es sql server 2008

Comment: Acabo de copiar y pegar el código y se ejecutó correctamente. Tengo la costumbre de probar el código que publico, por lo que me pareció extraño que hubiera un error. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta con el código que usaste? No logro replicar tu error.